# Get contracts based on users access SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query which gets the contracts a user has access to. However, no contracts are listed for the user, I need to be able to select all contracts. I'm not too sure how to go about this.

I've got a simply query (simple for this purpose - I've added joins to relevant tables, etc.):

```
SELECT contract FROM user
WHERE user.Login = @user
```

This works fine. However, if user A, for example, has no contracts (meaning access to all) 0 results are shown. In this case I need the query to select ALL contracts. I've tried using CASE, etc. But none seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't do that with a single SQL query. It's not about T-SQL, this simply isn't how SQL works. To do what you ask you need to *know in advance* if there are any matching records, which means executing that query. If not, you execute a different query without the `WHERE` clause. You could use [@@ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to check if the last query returned any rows, eg `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 SELECT contact FROM user`

Comment: *"You can't do that with a single SQL query."* This isn't true. You could easily include an `EXISTS` and an `OR` in the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to use an `EXISTS` an an `OR`:

```sql
SELECT contract
FROM dbo.[User] U --USER is a reserved keyword and should not be used for object names.
                  --I strongly recommend changing the name of this object
WHERE u.Login = @Name
   OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.[User] E --See above comment
                  WHERE E.Login = @name);
```